# How to update ng-pristine in Custom ControlValueAccessor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written a simple CustomValueAccessor to implement the pikaday datepicker. It works, but when I choose a date with the date picker and update the property, the inner input control (which is bound to the property with ngModel) does not update it's ng-pristine class, while the outer component does. I need the inner input to be marked as ng-touched and I can't figure out how to achieve that.

Here is my class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewEncapsulation, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

import { DateService } from "./shared";

import * as pikaday from 'pikaday'

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker.component.html',
  styles: [require('pikaday/css/pikaday.css')],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: [
    // providers to implement formControlName
    { 
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  /**
   * ID of the input element
   */
  @Input() id: string;

  /**
   * The minimum date the user can select. Defaults to today. Set to null to not require. 
   */
  @Input() minDate: Date = new Date();

  /**
   * Outputs the chosen date string
   */
  @Output('date') dateChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  /**
   * The formatted date value
   */
  private _date: string;

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Initialises the pikaday datepicker
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.id)
      throw "Id is required for datepicker"

    let options = { 
      field: document.getElementById(this.id),
      format: DateService.datePickerFormat,
      onSelect: date => {
        this.date = startDatePicker.toString();
      } 
    };
    if(this.minDate)
      options['minDate'] = this.minDate;

    let startDatePicker = new pikaday(options);
  }

  /**
   * Emits the new date
   */
  set date(value){
    this._date = value;
    this.onChangeCallback(value);
    this.onTouchedCallback(value);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the date value
   */
  get date(){
    return this._date;
  }

  /**
   * Push date to parent components (required by ControlValueAccessor)
   */
  onChangeCallback = (_: any) => {};

  /**
   * let formControlValue interface register a touch callback 
   */
  onTouchedCallback = (_: any) => {};

  /**
   * Allows parent component to set the onchange handler
   */
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Allows parent component to set an ontouch handler (not implemented)
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Called when the component is inited with formControlName
   */
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.date = value;
  }

}
```

And the template:

```
<input type="text" [id]="id" [(ngModel)]="date">
```

And here is the HTML before having set a value with the datepicker:

```
<datepicker formcontrolname="endDatePicker" id="endDatePicker" ng-reflect-id="endDatePicker" ng-reflect-name="endDatePicker" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"><input type="text" ng-reflect-model="" ng-reflect-id="endDatePicker" id="endDatePicker" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input type="text" ng-reflect-model="" ng-reflect-id="endDatePicker" id="endDatePicker" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
</datepicker>
```

And here it is afterwards:

```
<datepicker formcontrolname="endDatePicker" id="endDatePicker" ng-reflect-id="endDatePicker" ng-reflect-name="endDatePicker" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid"><input type="text" ng-reflect-model="19 October, 2016" ng-reflect-id="endDatePicker" id="endDatePicker" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <input type="text" ng-reflect-model="19 October, 2016" ng-reflect-id="endDatePicker" id="endDatePicker" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
</datepicker>
```

Note the classes: ng-pristine and ng-touched on the input control. As far as I'm concerned it should be ng-dirty, not ng-pristine.

Comment: Logically `ng-pristine` and `ng-touched` are set by the `onTouched` callback. Could you implement that part and see the result?

Comment: I've updated my question with ngTouched implemented - good idea, but unfortunately that wasn't the solution.